# Add aws cognito token to OAuth2PasswordBearer Fast Api

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, token, amazon-cognito, fastapi

I have implemented sign up and login successfully with amazon cognito and fast api, but now I want to secure other endpoints with returned token of aws.
these are functions implemented so far:

```
optional_oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="login", auto_error=False)
async def get_current_user(*, db: Session = Depends(deps.get_db), token: str = Depends(optional_oauth2_scheme)):
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, options={"verify_signature": False})
        user = UserController.get_user_by_email(db, payload.get('username'))
    except:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail='Invalid username or password')

    return user

def login(self, username, password, db: Session):
        client = boto3.client('cognito-idp',region_name=os.getenv('COGNITO_REGION_NAME'))

        try:
        response = client.initiate_auth(
            ClientId=os.getenv('COGNITO_USER_CLIENT_ID'),
            AuthFlow='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
            AuthParameters={
                'USERNAME': username,
                'PASSWORD': password
            }
        )
        user = controllers.user.get_by_email(db, username)
        if user:
            user.access_token = response['AuthenticationResult']['AccessToken']
            db.flush()
            db.commit()
            user = controllers.user.get_by_email(db, username)
           
            return {"detail": {'data': user}}
        else:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="That User doesn't exist")
```

now I want to use this function to logout endpoint and to have token to request headers.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: What do you mean with `logout`? `HTTP` is stateless, so you can perform a new request with no authentication header and it'll be as if you never authenticated. This may help https://www.ibm.com/cloud/learn/rest-apis in particular, point number 3, statelessness

Comment: it should be logout of amazon, not rest api

Comment: Ok, but then it seems from this medium post https://medium.com/@houzier.saurav/aws-cognito-with-python-6a2867dd02c6 that amazon cognito uses rest api as well. You can smply delete the token assigning to it the value of None

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.global_sign_out
this comments explains sign out
so I need token in header

Comment: This method only invalidates your token. You just have to implement it in `fastapi`